# script source jquery understand , what if CDN is down , how to get path in Aptana

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, aptana

The below code does not show a alert once the page is loaded.

If I change it to `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>` then it works fine. I am using Aptana plugin. I think I will have to give the actual path in case I don't want to rely on CDN. How can I find the path of this file locally. The project structure is listed below.

[image: Project Explorer]

[image: Path to Ruble]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery 1.6.4.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("In Ready");
            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your console output? I think it might be that you have a white space in your file name `jquery 1.6.4.js` and it might not actually load jQuery properly and thus fail. Also, why are you using such an outdated version?

Comment: How can I find it, please help me with the Aptana plugin usage